# Compiling with webpack into single file

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

So I have the following `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');

const JS_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, '/js');
const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'js');

const entry = {
    main: JS_DIR + '/main/main.js',
    all: JS_DIR + '/all.js',
};

const output = {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'js/main/[name].js'
};

const rules = [
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: [ JS_DIR ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        // Loaders enable us to bundle the static assets.
        use: 'babel-loader', // Allows for transpiling JS files using babel & webpack.
    }
];

module.exports = () => ({
    entry: entry,
    output: output,
    devtool: false, // Don't output any .map source files, otherwise 'source-map'.
    module: {
        rules: rules,
    }
});
```

Currently, when I run `npm run prod` I get the following build:

[image]

It builds the additional `/js` directory inside the `/js` directory and then it has `main/all.js and main/main.js`. The `all.js` inside there is empty, but the `main.js` is the compiled stuff.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

Instead of building the `/js` directory inside `/js`, how can I make the contents of `js/main/main.js` output to just the `all.js` in the main js directory? So basically like this:

[image]

All help would be appreciated!

Comment: At the moment you explicitly set the `output.filename` to be `js/main/[name].js`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, so I got it down to `filename: '[name].js',` which outputs to the same directory (This is great), but it makes an output to a `main.js` file, but also outputs an empty `all.js`, I would like to not output main.js and only output all.js (But take the output from main.js and have it inside all.js).